# Symfony2: do not update a form field if not provided

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, persistence

I have a form for my "Team" entity. This entity has an "image" field. This field is required on creation process, but not required on edit process. But right now, during edit process, if I don't provide any image in the file input, the empty input is still persisted, and so my database field is emptied during the process. 
How can I do to avoid persistence of this field, if nothing is provided in the form file input? So the entity keeps its old value for this field. Of course, if a file is provided, I want him to erase the old one.

My controller looks like this:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em->persist($team);
        $em->flush();
        ...
    }
}
```

and part of my entity, dealing with image (I'm pretty sure I have to do something in here, but don't know what exactly):

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function uploadImage() {
    // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if (null === $this->image) {
        return;
    }
    if(!$this->id){
        $this->image->move($this->getTmpUploadRootDir(), $this->image->getClientOriginalName());
    }else{
        $this->image->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->image->getClientOriginalName());
    }
    $this->setImage($this->image->getClientOriginalName());
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Ok, I did some changes to [this answer's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22558473/4257747) code, because apparently the event listener asks for a `FormEvent` instance in his callback, not a `FormInterface` instance.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
// Retrieve submitted data
$form = $event->getForm();
$item = $event->getData();

// Test if upload image is null (maybe adapt it to work with your code)
if (null !== $form->get('image')->getData()) {
    var_dump($form->get('image')->getData());
    die('image provided');
    $item->setImage($form->get('image')->getData());
}
```

});

When I provide an image, the script goes into the test, and `die()`, as expected. When I do not provide any file, the script doesn't go into the test `if()`, but my field in the database is still erased with an empty value. Any idea?

And as asked below, here is the Form

```
// src/Van/TeamsBundle/Form/TeamEditType.php

namespace Van\TeamsBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class TeamEditType extends TeamType // Ici, on hÃ©rite de ArticleType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // On fait appel Ã  la mÃ©thode buildForm du parent, qui va ajouter tous les champs Ã  $builder
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        // On supprime celui qu'on ne veut pas dans le formulaire de modification
        $builder->remove('image')
        ->add('image', 'file', array(
            'data_class' => null,
            'required' => false
        ))
        ;


        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
            // Retrieve submitted data
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $item = $event->getData();

            // Test if upload image is null (maybe adapt it to work with your code)
            if (null !== $form->get('image')->getData()) {
                var_dump($form->get('image')->getData());
                die('image provided');
                $item->setImage($form->get('image')->getData());
            }
        });


    }

    // On modifie cette mÃ©thode car les deux formulaires doivent avoir un nom diffÃ©rent
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'van_teamsbundle_teamedittype';
    }
}
```

and the whole Team entity:

```
<?php

namespace Van\TeamsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Team
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Van\TeamsBundle\Entity\TeamRepository") @ORM\Table(name="van_teams")
 */
class Team
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="countryCode", type="string", length=2)
     */
    private $countryCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Van\TeamsBundle\Entity\Game")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $game;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Van\TeamsBundle\Entity\Statut")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $statut;

    /**
     * @var string $image
     * @Assert\File( maxSize = "1024k", mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid Image")
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $image;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Team
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set countryCode
     *
     * @param string $countryCode
     * @return Team
     */
    public function setCountryCode($countryCode)
    {
        $this->countryCode = $countryCode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get countryCode
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCountryCode()
    {
        return $this->countryCode;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param string $image
     * @return Team
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Set game
     *
     * @param \Van\TeamsBundle\Entity\Game $game
     * @return Team
     */
    public function setGame(\Van\TeamsBundle\Entity\Game $game)
    {
        $this->game = $game;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get game
     *
     * @return \Van\TeamsBundle\Entity\Game 
     */
    public function getGame()
    {
        return $this->game;
    }

    /**
     * Set statut
     *
     * @param \Van\TeamsBundle\Entity\Statut $statut
     * @return Team
     */
    public function setStatut(\Van\TeamsBundle\Entity\Statut $statut)
    {
        $this->statut = $statut;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get statut
     *
     * @return \Van\TeamsBundle\Entity\Statut 
     */
    public function getStatut()
    {
        return $this->statut;
    }






    public function getFullImagePath() {
        return null === $this->image ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir(). $this->image;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir() {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
        // return $this->getTmpUploadRootDir();
        return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/uploads/';
    }

    protected function getTmpUploadRootDir() {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
        return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/uploads_tmp/';
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function uploadImage() {
        // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
        if (null === $this->image) {
            return;
        }
        if(!$this->id){
            $this->image->move($this->getTmpUploadRootDir(), $this->image->getClientOriginalName());
        }else{
            $this->image->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->image->getClientOriginalName());
        }
        $this->setImage($this->image->getClientOriginalName());
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     */
    public function moveImage()
    {
        if (null === $this->image) {
            return;
        }
        if(!is_dir($this->getUploadRootDir())){
            mkdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
        }
        copy($this->getTmpUploadRootDir().$this->image, $this->getFullImagePath());
        unlink($this->getTmpUploadRootDir().$this->image);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreRemove()
     */
    public function removeImage()
    {
        unlink($this->getFullImagePath());
        rmdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

I did that. When I provide an image, it is saved in the image field in the database and redirection to my index page occurs. When I don't provide any image, redirection doesn't occur, and the following message appears above my file input in my form: "The file could not be found." In my `TeamEditType` class, I did the following, so the image should not be required.

```
$builder->remove('image')
->add('image', 'file', array(
    'data_class' => null,
    'required' => false
))
;
```

Answer (score 18):

As of Symfony 2.3, you can simply use the **PATCH** http method, as documented [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#method).

```
    $form = $this->createForm(FooType::class, $foo, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('foo_update', array('id' => $foo->getId())),
        'method' => 'PATCH',
    ));
```

It's an easy way to make a partial update of an entity using your main form, without rendering all the fields.

Comment: Amazing. Best solution i think

Answer (score 7):

One approach in Symfony 2.4 (further information in [Symfony2 coockbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)) :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
 // $builder->add() ... 

 $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormInterface $form) {
        // Retrieve submitted data
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $image = $form->getData();

        // Test if upload image is null (maybe adapt it to work with your code)
        if (null !== $form->get('uploadImage')->getData()) {
            $image->setUploadImage($form->get('uploadImage')->getData());
        }
    });
}
```

### Edit

It seems that you already test your prepersit data. Try the following :

```
   public function setImage($image)
   {
        if($image !== null) {
            $this->image = $image;

            return $this;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: added "edit 2" part in my original post. can u take a look ? i dont understand why this message appears. something to do with Entity ORM annotations maybe ?

Comment: Have a look in the [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) to see how they manage file. Particularly in the upload() method before persisting the entity. It seems that for a file they don't use "require", I guess...

Comment: I did spend lot of time on the cookbook, but i can't figure what is going wrong with my scripts.. i did pretty much what they do. what do you mean by "they dont use require" ? you mean "required" => false when setting the field in the builder ?

Comment: Yes... When you read the "file" can be blank but they don't use required attribute.

Comment: yes, but if i don't specify "required" => false, then "required" is implicitly set to true, and when i submit my form with empty file, the form doesn't submit and ask me to fill this field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using symfony 3.3 and faced the same issue, below is the solution how I overcome it.

You need to create a extra property for image uploading in your entity other than image property, something like $file;

Product.php

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string")
 *
 */
 private $image;

/**
 *
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png" })
 */
private $file;

public function setFile($file)
{
    $this->file = $file;
    return $this;
}
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}

// other code i.e image setter getter 
...
```

ProductType.php

```
   $builder->add('file', FileType::class, array(
            'data_class' => null,
            'required'=>false,
            'label' => 'Upload Image (jpg, jpeg, png file)')
   );
```

Form.html.twig

```
  <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.file) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.file, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>
```

Finally ProductController.php

```
 ...
 if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
     $file = $item->getFile();
              if($file instanceof UploadedFile) {
                  $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
                  $file->move(
                  $this->getParameter('upload_directory'),
                  $fileName
                  );
                  $item->setImage($fileName);
              }
  ...
  }
 ...
```

Little more about `upload_directory`

app/config/config.html

```
 parameters:
    upload_directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/web/uploads'
```

Create a `uploads` directory in web dir.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using PHP Reflection API. My approach was to browse the attributes of the entity class and replace the values not provided in the query with those already saved.

```
/**
 * @param \ReflectionClass $reflectionClass
 * @param $entity
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Request
 */
public function formatRequest($class, $entity, Request $request){

    $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass('AppBundle\Entity\\'.$class);

    foreach ($reflectionClass->getProperties() as $attribut)
    {
        $attribut->setAccessible(true); // to avoid fatal error when trying to access a non-public attribute

        if($request->request->get($attribut->getName()) == null) { // if the attribute value is not provided in the request
            $request->request->set($attribut->getName(), $attribut->getValue($entity)); 
        }
    }

    return $request;
}
```

And then I use it like this :

```
$request = $this->formatRequest("EntityName", $entity, $request);
```

This is really generic.